# Ansible loop with json and with_items for array?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to set up some elasticsearch roles using the api with ansible and when I run my code I seem to get this below rather than the expected

Incorrect
        "indices" : [
      {
        "names" : [
          "docker-*, logstash-*, .kibana"
        ],
        "privileges" : [
          "read view_index_metadata"
        ],

expected outcome when I view the role

```
    "indices" : [
  {
    "names" : [
      "docker*",
      "springxd-*",
      "logstash-*"
    ],
```

I am using an ansible loop

```
  - name: Setup Special kibana Roles for Spaces which are later mapped to LDAP
uri:
  url: "https://{{ ansible_fqdn }}:9200/_xpack/security/role/{{ item.role_name }}"
  method: PUT
  user: '{{ vault_elastic_user }}'
  password: '{{ vault_elastic_pass }}'
  body: '{ "indices": [ { "names": [ "{{ item.index_names }}" ], "privileges": [ "{{ item.privileges }}" ], "field_security" : { "grant" : [ "*" ] } } ] }'
  body_format: json
  validate_certs: no
  headers:
    Content-Type: "application/json"
with_items:
  - { role_name: app_components_role, index_names: 'docker-*, logstash-*, .kibana, springxd-*', privileges: 'read, view_index_metadata' }
```

Any idea how to make the get the right outcome?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If your value here, your 'index_names' doesn't have any quotes. Ansible isn't going to magically add them, at least not when you are j ust using 'index_names' as a string.

```
with_items:
  - { role_name: app_components_role, index_names: 'docker-*, logstash-*, .kibana, springxd-*', privileges: 'read, view_index_metadata' }
```

Maybe adjust your item to look like this?

```
with_items:
  - { role_name: app_components_role, index_names: '"docker-*", "logstash-*", ".kibana", "springxd-*"', privileges: '"read", "view_index_metadata"' }
```

Or maybe this if yoiu also want to make it more readable.

```
with_items:
  - role_name: app_components_role
    index_names: '"docker-*", "logstash-*", ".kibana", "springxd-*"'
    privileges: '"read", "view_index_metadata"'
```

Or if you want to go with the even better readability adjust to something like this maybe.

```
uri:
  ...
  body: |
    { "indices": [ 
      { "names": {{ item.index_names | to_json }},
        "privileges": {{ item.privileges | to_json }}, 
        "field_security" : { "grant" : [ "*" ] }
      } ]
    }
  ...
with_items:
  - role_name: app_components_role
    index_names:
    - docker-*
    - logstash-*
    - .kibana
    - springxd-*
    privileges:
    - read
    - view_index_metadata
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions before i originally posted but ran your suggestion and all I get is an error back from ansible that is too long to post here.

Comment: Then use a gist/hastebin/pastebin/etc.  Or just read through the error, and post the relevant bits.  Keep in mind that what I posted is untested examples, I don't  have any good ways to test your code.  You almost certainly are going to have carefully read the errors, and fix things a bit.

Comment: I was able to get the expected result once I removed quotes from around the items in the json body 
{ "names": [ {{ item.index_names }} ], "privileges": [ {{ item.privileges }} ], "field_security" :

Comment: Probably something left over from too may attempts to make it working